# Raspberry pi HQ camera PNG capture taking a long time at full res

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, raspicam

Does anyone know what factors the PNG capture takes a long time (16 seconds in well lit conditions and size 11MB) to capture at full sensor size (4056x3040) using the HQ camera?

Is it mostly processing the image?
Can you point me to what affects speed of processing?

Also this is on a Pi4 4GB, running raspbian